# notify_url is not getting called

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

every time im starting using PayPal ipn and stuff im getting stuck and my code isn't working.

So today my problem is my ipn doesn't get called, and that's funny cause actually its was working 2 days ago.

my form (button) :

```
require ('../init.php');

if(!$_GET['id'] || !$userfunc->IsPlanIDExist($_GET['id']))
{
  return;
}

$array = $userfunc->GetPlanArray($_GET['id']);

?>
<form name="myform" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$userfunc->GetSitePayPal()?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?=$userfunc->GetSiteURL()?>core/php/paypal/checkpayment.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=$userfunc->GetSiteURL()?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$userfunc->GetSiteURL()?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="paypal" />
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$array['name']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="<?=$array['name']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$array['price']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $array['id']?>"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.myform.submit();
    </script>
  </form>
```

when I check the source everything is okay and should be working fine as it was.
but today when I checked my purchase again it's not working and 2 days ago it was working fine, I didn't touch my system at all.

Im using PayPal ipn code example from the GitHub so anything should be working fine.

Comment: You got any error in your browser console while doing this payment process.

Comment: @AlivetoDie nothing, I've tried to write to files with file_put_contents when its only getting called and getting nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to see what POST or GET data you are receiving? I think PP made some breaking changes. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015077/paypal-ipn-post-variable-txn-id-not-being-set